# How to make MariaDB/mySQL INSERTs into multiple tables appear atomic to other database connections

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using MariaDB 10.3 (I presume mySQL behaves similarly), to which I make several concurrent connections.

From one of those connections, I insert the same value (let's say 'xxx' below) into several different tables, like so:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO table1 (col) VALUES (xxx);
INSERT INTO table2 (col) VALUES (xxx);
INSERT INTO table3 (col) VALUES (xxx);
COMMIT;
```

From **other** connections, I perform periodic `SELECTS` 'polling' for changes to the tables (in the same table order as the `INSERTs`):

```
SELECT FROM table1 WHERE col=xxx;
SELECT FROM table2 WHERE col=xxx;
SELECT FROM table3 WHERE col=xxx;
```

I need `SELECTSs` from these tables to be 'made visible' in the same order as the `INSERTs` were made (so changes to `table1` always appear before changes to `table2`, and similarly `table2` always before `table3`). If they all appear together atomically, then that is also OK.

However, if I repeat this many thousands of times, **very rarely**, I find that my `SELECTs` return changes to `table3` without changes to `table1` or `table2` (changes to `table1` or `table2` appear later, during the next poll).

I understand that this is caused by a race condition: The `INSERT` transaction executes in between the `SELECTs` from `table2` and `table3`.

How can this be avoided? Must I use some combination of transactions and/or table/row locking on the other connections?

Comment: What do you mean by "wedget between the SELECTs"?

Comment: I mean that SELECT table1 is executed, then SELECT table2, then the INSERT transaction, then SELECT table3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by using `LOCK TABLES ... READ` around my `SELECT`s